# Cascade new IDs to a second, related table

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, insert-update

I have two tables, Contacts and Contacts_Detail. I am importing records into the Contacts table and need to run a SP to create a record in the Contacts_Detail table for each new record in the Contacts. There is an ID in the Contacts table and a matching ID_D in the Contacts_Detail table.

I'm using this to insert the record into Contacts_Detail but get the 'Subquery returned more than 1 value.' error and I can't figure out why. There are multiple records in Contacts that need have matching records in Contacts_Detail.

```
  Insert into Contacts_Detail (ID_D)

  select id from Contacts c
  left join Contacts_Detail cd
  on c.id = cd.id_d
  where id_d is null
```

I'm open to a better way... 
thanks.

Comment: Do you have any triggers on your Contacts_Detail table?

Comment: Is that your real query? I don't see a subquery..

Comment: The query you've posted looks fine and can't possibly be causing this error (unless, as @Kevin suggested, there is a trigger you're not telling us about).

Comment: Also can you include details about how you are "importing"?

Comment: Kevin you hit it on the head... it was a trigger on the table causing the error. I was too close to the forest, thanks for pointing out the tree.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're inserting blank child-records into your Contacts_Detail table -- so the first question I'd ask is: Why?

As for why your specific SQL isn't working...

A few things you can check:

- Contacts table -- do you have any records there `WHERE id is null`? 
  (delete them -- then make the id field a primary key)
- Contacts_Detail
  table -- do you have any records there `WHEERE id_d is null`? 
  (delete them -- then go into your designer and create a relationship
  / enforce referential integrity.)
- Verify that c.id is the primary
  key, and cd.id_d is the correct foreign key to relate the tables.

Hope that helps

Comment: There is a lot more data that goes into the record beyond the ID, I found that once I stripped out all of the other data I still got the error. Once that was solved, ther rest was straight forward. The ID is the primary key on the record.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have a trigger? This seems a little simpler than having to determine for all time which rows are missing - that seems more like something you would do periodically to correct for some anomalies, not something you should have to do after every insert. Something like this should work:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.NewContacts
ON dbo.Contacts
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT dbo.Contacts_Detail(ID_D) SELECT ID FROM inserted;
END
GO
```

But I suspect you have a trigger on the `Contacts_Detail` table that is not written to correctly handle multi-row inserts, and that's where your subquery error is coming from. Can you show the trigger on `Contacts_Detail`?